# Is it possible to type check the parameters for an optional protocol method?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, selector

On iOS4, if I have a non-public protocol like:

```
@protocol HTTPDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void) methodDidFinish:(NSDictionary *) response;
- (void) methodDidFail:(NSString *) error;
@end
```

And I have a pointer to a delegate like:

```
id<HTTPDelegate> delegate;
```

Then, I want to optionally call that delegate method:

```
if( [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(methodDidFail:)] ) {
  [delegate methodDidFail:errorString];
}
```

That works great. However, I later decide to use an NSError* for the error and change the protocol to:

```
@protocol HTTPDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void) methodDidFinish:(NSDictionary *) response;
- (void) methodDidFail:(NSError *) error;
@end
```

If I just change the type of one parameter in an optional protocol method, the compiler won't complain when I check (with respondsToSelector:) if the delegate implements that method and it will let me pass errorString with the methodDidFail: message. Instead, later, at runtime, this will result in an invalid selector crash.

What if I want the compiler to complain and check the types of the parameters? Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way to do check the parameter types. Better you add a new method when you change the types. I'd name the delegate methods like so:

```
- (void) methodDidFailWithError:(NSError *) error;

- (void) methodDidFailWithString:(NSString *) errorString;
```

Comment: I think this is acceptable as a workaround, although it isn't exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: `didFailWithErrorMessage` would be better.